# Xamarin iOS - Drawing onto image after scaling it

Tags: ios, uiimageview, drawing, xamarin, scale

I have an app where the user can draw freely on a loaded image. He chooses a pencil color, and start drawing onto the image.

Along with that, he can scale the image down and up, using the fingers, that's where i'm having problems.

**After scaling, when drawing onto the image, it gets blurry, and strangely shrinks..**

**Code for scaling:**

```
void ScaleImage (UIPinchGestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer)
        {
            AdjustAnchorPoint (gestureRecognizer);
            if (gestureRecognizer.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began || gestureRecognizer.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed) {
                gestureRecognizer.View.Transform *= CGAffineTransform.MakeScale (gestureRecognizer.Scale, gestureRecognizer.Scale);
                gestureRecognizer.Scale = 1;
            }
        }
```

**Code for drawing:**

```
public override void TouchesBegan (NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
            {
                base.TouchesBegan (touches, evt);

                if (!canDraw)
                    return;

                UITouch touch = (UITouch)touches.AnyObject;
                lastPoint = touch.LocationInView (MyImageView);
            }

public override void TouchesMoved (NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
        {
            base.TouchesMoved (touches, evt);

            if (!canDraw)
                return;

            UITouch touch       = (UITouch)touches.AnyObject;
            PointF currentPoint = touch.LocationInView (MyImageView);

            UIGraphics.BeginImageContext (MyImageView.Frame.Size);

            MyImageView.Image.Draw (new RectangleF (
                0, 0,
                MyImageView.Frame.Size.Width,
                MyImageView.Frame.Size.Height));

            CGContext ctx = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ();
            ctx.SetLineCap (CGLineCap.Round);
            ctx.SetLineWidth (5.0f);
            ctx.SetRGBStrokeColor (red, green, blue, 1);

            CGPath path = new CGPath ();
            path.MoveToPoint(MyImageView.Transform, lastPoint.X, lastPoint.Y);
            path.AddLineToPoint (MyImageView.Transform, currentPoint.X, currentPoint.Y);
            ctx.AddPath (path);
            ctx.DrawPath (CGPathDrawingMode.Stroke);

            MyImageView.Image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext ();
            UIGraphics.EndImageContext ();

            lastPoint = currentPoint;
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made it work by using Bezier Paths instead of Core Graphics.

**You can find some background about Bezier Paths here:**
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html

Since i wanted to implement an Undo button, i created a Class for storing the Color of the line, as well as the corresponding Path:

```
public class VESLine{
public UIBezierPath Path {
    get;
    set;
}

public UIColor Color {
    get;
    set;
}

public byte Index {
    get;
    set;
}
}
```

The `TouchesBegan` event was modified accordingly, to create a new UIBezierPath object, store it in the array, along with its Color and Index, and touch location:

```
public override void TouchesBegan (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
{
    IndexCount++;

    UIBezierPath path   = new UIBezierPath ();
    path.LineWidth      = 5.0f;

    UITouch touch   = (UITouch)touches.AnyObject;
    previousPoint1  = touch.PreviousLocationInView (this);

    PointF p = touch.LocationInView (this);
    path.MoveTo (p);

    InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
        this.SetNeedsDisplay ();
    });

    currentPath = path;

    VESLine line = new VESLine () {
        Path    = currentPath, 
        Color   = StrokeColor,
        Index   = IndexCount 
    };
    lines.Add(line);
}
```

`TouchesMoved` event was also modified, to create a smooth line path, by using a QuadCurve instead of a regular line. I also call the `SetNeedsDisplay` method, to force view drawing:

```
public override void TouchesMoved (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
{
    UITouch touch   = (UITouch)touches.AnyObject;
    PointF p        = touch.LocationInView (this);

    if (Math.Abs (p.X - previousPoint1.X) >= 4 ||
        Math.Abs (p.Y - previousPoint1.Y) >= 4) {

        PointF cP = new PointF ((p.X + previousPoint1.X) / 2, (p.Y + previousPoint1.Y) / 2);

        currentPath.AddQuadCurveToPoint (cP, previousPoint1);
        previousPoint1 = p;
    }
    else
        currentPath.AddLineTo (p);

    InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
        this.SetNeedsDisplay ();
    });
}
```

`TouchesEnded` and `TouchesCancelled` will redraw the view:

```
public override void TouchesEnded (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
{
    InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
        this.SetNeedsDisplay ();
    });
}

public override void TouchesCancelled (MonoTouch.Foundation.NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
{
    InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
        this.SetNeedsDisplay ();
    });
}
```

Finally, the `Draw` method was rewritten to iterate the Array of paths, drawing each one of them using the corresponding color:

```
public override void Draw (System.Drawing.RectangleF rect)
{
    foreach (VESLine p in lines) {
        p.Color.SetStroke ();
        p.Path.Stroke ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. It definitely helped me out. I also wanted to add that, I was getting some crazy looking spikes coming from the drawn on lines and I was able to fix this by including the following properties in the `UIBezierPath` object within `TouchesBegan`: `UIBezierPath path = new UIBezierPath {
    LineJoinStyle = CGLineJoin.Round,
    LineCapStyle = CGLineCap.Round
};`

Comment: Not that I doubt you, but according to the Bezier path documentation, it's just a wrapper around standard CGPath related features, so what can it do that you can't already do with CGPath?